# PowerShell WinRM memory limit and Start-Process

Tags: powershell, winrm

I'm trying to run `Start-Process` over WinRM (`Invoke-Command`), and the application keeps telling me that it has run out of memory. It tops out at about 45000K and will then exit. However, if I run the exact same command on the computer I'm remoting into, the process will happily go over that ceiling.

I understand that there's a memory limit for WinRM sessions, so:

1. Are processes started by `Start-Process` bound to the same memory limit as the WinRM Session?
2. How can I work around this limit?

(If it matters, previously in the same session some files (~10MB) are sent over to the remote machine via WinRM.)

Comment: See [here](https://serverfault.com/q/198197/397030). (The second answer is also an answer to your first question: yes, they're limited just the same, because all processes become part of the job WinRM is part of.) You can try creating the process outside the job object, but that seems like a fairly complicated exercise. Potentially simpler (if you don't need to interact with the process directly) is to create an on-demand scheduled task to run it instead, as that will not be restricted in the same way.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks for the link - I only need to know when the process exits so a scheduled task *might* work.